# run a c++ code in notepad++

Tags: c++, notepad++

I downloaded notepad++ for IDE and try to run a very simple code with it but I don't know how to run that code.
This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{  std::cout << "Hello , my programmer!\n" ;
return 0;
}
```

but when I press F5 a window promote and when I click on Run it open Notepad++ folder.

Comment: Notepad++ isn't a compiler. Download GCC or Visual Studio.

Comment: Notepad++ is more accurately classified as a [text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor). It's not an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). Of course, these classifications are not always so clearcut, and Notepad++ does have some useful features that are normally characteristic of IDEs, such as syntax highlighting and code completion, but it does not provide or integrate build tools, so it's definitely not an IDE. If you're going to use Notepad++ to edit your C++ source, you're going to have to compile and run it separately from Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ is a text editor, it is not IDE. It means you can write code in it but you can't compile the program or launch it from there.

You should google for what IDE you need for your platform, Visual Studio Community Edition is free for example.